# Вызов из "соседней функции"

Tags: javascript

Есть две функции `one()` и `two()`. В функции `one()` устанавливается слушатель на элемент. В функции `two()` его надо снять, когда происходит событие в функции `two()`. То есть каким образом я могу получить ссылку на `doSomething()`, которая находится в функции `one()` из функции `two()`

```js
function one() {
  // something is running
  function doSomething() {
    // doSomething
  }
  elDo.addEventListener('click', doSomething)

}

function two() {
  one()

  function stopAll() {
    // doSomething
    // Как здесь убрать слушатель с elDo???
  }


  elStop.addEventListener('click', stopAll)
}


two()
```

Comment: `removeEventListener`

Comment: Игорь, вопрос заключается в другом

Comment: @elarri а в чём?

Comment: в том, что в функции two() слушатель из one() не снимается... Как минимум функция two() не видит ф-ию doSomething()

Comment: а зачем ей видеть функцию doSomething?

Comment: ну насколько я понимаю, снимая слушатель, надо вторым аргументом указать ф-ию на которую он ставился, т.е. elDo.removeEventListener('click', doSomething)

Comment: То есть полный вопрос заключается: как из пула (списка) событий на конкретный элемент удалить конкретный его обработчик, а не просто удалить слушателя с элемента

Comment: Не совсем. Я дополнил свой вопрос. Если просто - мне надо в ф-ии two() получить ссылку на doSomething(), которая находится в ф-ии one(). Я так понимаю, что получив данную сслыку я могу снять слушатель, кликнув по elStop

Answer (score 2):

Получить доступ к локальной переменной или функции "снаружи" - невозможно.

Самым простым вариантом решения, в данном случае, является сохранение ссылки на слушатель события в чем-то внешнем по отношению к `one` и `two`: либо в переменной вне обеих функций (на уровне их объявления, или выше); либо в свойстве объекта (для этого можно и DOM-объект, и объект функции использовать); либо в свойстве `window`, что аналогично глобальной переменной.

Вариант со свойством `window`:

```
function one() {
  /* .... */
  window._elDoHandler = elDo.addEventListener('click', doSomething);
  /* .... */
}

function two() {
  /* .... */
  function stopAll() {
    if (window._elDoHandler)
      elDo.removeEventListener('click', window._elDoHandler);
  }
  /* .... */
}
```

Ну а при хранении ссылки в свойстве самого DOM-объекта, вместо `window._elDoHandler` - использовать (например) `elDo._clickHandler`. А вариант использования внешней переменной, и без примера должен быть ясен.

---

Еще можно организовать "автоматическое" хранение всех добавленных слушателей в кастомном свойстве `eventListeners`... Реализация обновлений свойства через перекрытие прототипных методов - довольно простая (хоть и весьма многобуквенная):

```js
/* этот вызов просто прячет пугающе "пухлую" реализацию,
 * он для ее перемещения в конец примера 
 * (т.к. при реальном использовании таких вещей, их 
 * подключают к документу в <head>, как и полиффилы). */
overrideListenerMethods();

// выберем из документа элементики...
const elDo = document.querySelector('#do'), 
      elStop = document.querySelector('#stop'); 

// ...и далее - применение нашего кастомного свойства в коде из вопроса
function one() {
  console.log('something is running'); 
  function doSomething() {
    console.log('doSomething'); 
  }
  elDo.addEventListener('click', doSomething); 
  // вывод всех слушателей события 'click' из свойства eventListeners (просто демо)
  console.log('[add] listeners:', ...elDo.eventListeners.click.entries()); 
}

function two() {
  one(); 
  elStop.addEventListener('click', stopAll); 

  function stopAll() {
    // удаление всех слушателей события 'click' на элементе elDo
    for (const listener of elDo.eventListeners.click.keys()) 
      elDo.removeEventListener('click', listener); 
    // ну и затем опять вывод слушателей, точнее их отсутствия :)
    console.log('[remove] listeners:', ...elDo.eventListeners.click.entries()); 
  }
}

two();


// ------------------------------------------------
function overrideListenerMethods() {
  // перекрытие addEventListener
  EventTarget.prototype._addEventListener = EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener; 
  EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = function (type, listener, option) {
    const capture = Boolean(typeof option === 'object' ? option.capture : option), 
          listenersKey = capture ? 'capturingEventListeners' : 'eventListeners', 
          listeners = this[listenersKey] = (this[listenersKey] || Object.create(null)), 
          listenersForType = listeners[type] = (listeners[type] || new Map()), 
          handler = listener.handleEvent || listener; 
    if (listenersForType.has(listener)) return listenersForType.get(handler); 
    listenersForType.set(listener, { option, /* можно хранить что-то еще. Например, кастомный tag обработчика, или время добавления, да что угодно */ }); 
    this._addEventListener(type, listener, option); 
    return handler;   // это добавлено для возможности вызова обработчика сразу после его добавления слушателем события (нередко такое требуется)
  }; 

  // перекрытие removeEventListener
  EventTarget.prototype._removeEventListener = EventTarget.prototype.removeEventListener; 
  EventTarget.prototype.removeEventListener = function (type, listener, option) {
    const capture = Boolean(typeof option === 'object' ? option.capture : option), 
          listenersKey = capture ? 'capturingEventListeners' : 'eventListeners', 
          listenersForType = this[listenersKey]?.[type]; 
    if (listenersForType instanceof Map)
      listenersForType.delete(listener);
    this._removeEventListener(type, listener, option); 
    return listenersForType;  // это для возможности вызвать по цепочке какой-то другой метод хранилища, после удаления слушателя
  }; 
}
```

```html
<button id="do">Do</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
```

Тут в качестве хранилища использован объект с вложенными `Map`, т.к. перечисление слушателей (используемых в роли ключей) отдельно от хранимых параметров может быть удобным. Плюс, удобная проверка наличия слушателя методом `has`, и сохранение порядка добавления слушателей. Конечно, для надежности стоит перекрыть возможность вызова Map-методов `add` и `delete` из внешнего кода, или даже описать все через кастомные типы... но это всего лишь пример, на уровне идеи. Его развитие/переработка это дело вкуса.

Зачем используется оберточный объект - для того чтобы слушатели сгруппировать по типу (имени) события. То есть, `evtTarget.eventListeners[типСобытия]` возвращает Map-коллекцию слушателей событий указанного типа (при ее наличии, конечно): это слегка подслащивает синтаксис. Слушатели для этапов всплытия и захвата хранятся отдельно, по понятным причинам.

Для соответствия стандартным методам, реализация в примере поддерживает в качестве слушателей как функции, так и объекты интерфейса `EventListener`.
Поведение при повторном добавлении слушателей, а именно логика "ссылочных дубликатов" - тоже соответствует стандартному методу (см. раздел «Multiple identical event listeners» в статье MDN об `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
const btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');

function one() {
  btn1.addEventListener('click', function() { console.log('click one'); });
}

function two() {
  btn1.oldAddEventListener = btn1.addEventListener;
  btn1.addEventListener = function(a1, a2, a3) {
    this.eventToRemove = { a1, a2, a3 };
    this.oldAddEventListener(a1, a2, a3);
  }

  one();

  btn1.addEventListener = btn1.oldAddEventListener;
  delete btn1.oldAddEventListener;
  btn1.addEventListener('click', function() { 
    console.log('click two'); 
    this.removeEventListener(btn1.eventToRemove.a1, btn1.eventToRemove.a2, btn1.eventToRemove.a3);
  });
}
btn2.addEventListener('click', two);
```

```html
<button id="btn1">Click</button><button id="btn2">Remove After Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const elDo = document.getElementById('bdo');
const elStop = document.getElementById('bstop');

function one() {

    function doSomething() {
        console.log('doSomething');
    }
    elDo.addEventListener('click', elDo.handler = doSomething);

}

function two() {
    one();
    function stopAll() {
        console.log('stopAll');
        elDo.removeEventListener('click', elDo.handler);
    }

    elStop.addEventListener('click', stopAll);
}

two();
```

```html
<button id="bdo">One</button>
<button id="bstop">Two</button>
```

Не кидайтесь камнями, задачу автора вопроса решает.